# Undefined in country flag UI in vue-tel-input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-tel-input

[Error in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7We1.png)

[Error in the dev tools inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbt8u.png)

Beside the country flag, undefined is coming. How to resolve this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across the same issue and figured out the solution from their source code:
[source code](https://github.com/iamstevendao/vue-tel-input/blob/master/src/components/vue-tel-input.vue)

```html
<slot name="arrow-icon" :open="open">
  <span class="vti__dropdown-arrow">{{ open ? "▲" : "▼" }}</span>
</slot>
```

If you look at the code above, the part which becomes 'undefined' is actually the arrow symbol and there should be default settings in the slot, where somehow this default setting is not working. As it is a Vue slot, you can simply fix it by defining your own arrow symbols here:

```html
<vue-tel-input
v-model="phoneNumber"
@open="onDropdownOpen(true)"
@close="onDropdownOpen(false)"
>
<template v-slot:arrow-icon>
  <span>{{ open ? '▲' : '▼' }}</span>
</template>
</vue-tel-input>
```

Then it should be all good.

Comment: In adidtion to this answer you can write onDropdownOpen like that   
                     onDropdownOpen(value){
      this.open = value
    },